# Como faço para verificar com nodejs, se uma tabela está sem registos?

Tags: node.js

Bom, pretendo fazer uma verificação a uma tabela com nodejs, para ver se a mesma está sem registos.

Como posso fazer isso de forma a que não dê erro, com nodejs?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica o `.length` do resultado:

```
db.query('SELECT * from tabela', (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res, res.length); // deve dar null, [], 0
    if (res.length == 0){
        console.log('A tabela está vazia!');
    }
});
```